# Set a variable for a class from an object and access the same value from another object of that class

Tags: java, oop

Here are the three classes.

1. input.java
2. Middle.java
3. Output.java

In this scenario, Middle.java has a static global variable x.

I'm setting the value of x from the input.java class using setter method.
and now I want to access the same value of x from the output.java using getter method. But when I try to do this, it doesn't do that. 
Here are the class files.

1. Input.java

   ```
    public class Input {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           Middle m = new Middle();
           m.setX(100);
       }
   }
   ```

2.Middle.java

```
    public class Middle {
public static int x;

public void setX(int value)
{
    x = value;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}
}
```

3. Ouput.java

```
    public class Output {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Middle m = new Middle();
    int temp = m.getX();
    System.out.print(temp);
}
}
```

So, when I run the input.java program first and set the value to 100 and then run the output.java program, the output I must get is 100. but I don't get that.

Comment: So you ran the program two times? Are you aware that everything gets reset after a program has finished running?

Comment: Yes @Sweeper . I know. But i want to achieve that functionality. How can I do that? Any alternative ?

Comment: One way is to write the value to a file somewhere and read it when you need it.

Comment: Okay. That's a good idea. Can you show me the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, values held in objects will become inaccessible after your program stops running. Therefore, you need to store the value somewhere permanently so it can be read the next time you run the program.

One way to do this is to write the value to a file on your hard drive:

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/some/path/to/a/file.txt")) {
    writer.write(yourValue);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then you can read it like this:

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("/Users/mulangsu/Desktop/temp.txt")) {
    System.out.println(reader.read());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another way to do this is to save your values to a web server. This way, your value can persist over different devices.